# Can Laravel be used as backend for existing HTML website template?

Tags: php, html, laravel

I have created a html template for a salon listing directory website but I also need a backend to add listings, add ads etc. Is it possible to integrate Laravel based admin panel to an existing project?

Answer (score 2):

Yes definaltely you can use Laravel since its developed using php

Laravel has lots of features it will make your work faster .

[image]

Image from
https://coderseye.com/best-php-frameworks-for-web-developers/

features of PHP Laravel Framework that make it popular among developers and businesses alike:

1. **Template Engine**
   Laravel framework is highly acknowledged for its inbuilt lightweight templates that help you create amazing layouts using dynamic content seeding. In addition to this, it has multiple widgets incorporating CSS and JS code with solid structures. The templates of laravel frameworks are innovatively designed to create a simple layout with distinctive sections.
2. **Artisan**
   Laravel offers a built-in tool for command line known as Artisan which allows performing the majority of those tedious and repetitive programming tasks that many developers avoid performing manually. These artisans can also be utilized to create the database structure, a skeleton code, and build their migration that becomes pretty easy-to-manage the database system. In addition, it can be interlaced to generate the basic MVC files right away through the command-line and manage those assets and their respective configurations. Artisan even helps developers to create their own commands and do convenient things with it.
3. **Eloquent ORM (object-relational mapping)**
   Laravel framework offers the Eloquent ORM that includes a simple PHP Active Record implementation. It lets the web app developers issue database queries with PHP syntax rather than writing SQL code. Every table in the database possesses a corresponding Model through which the developer interacts with said table. An ORM is relatively faster than all other PHP frameworks.
4. **Libraries & Modular:**
   Laravel is also popular due to its Object Oriented libraries as well as many other pre-installed libraries. These pre-installed libraries are not found in any other PHP frameworks. One of the preinstalled libraries is an Authentication library which is easy-to-implement and has many latest features, such as checking active users, Bcrypt hashing, password reset, CSRF (Cross-site Request Forgery) protection, and encryption. Furthermore, this framework is divided into individual modules that adopt modern PHP principles allowing developers to build responsive, modular, and handy web apps.
5. **MVC Architecture Support:**
   The MVC pattern of laravel ensures clarity of logic and presentation. This architecture support helps in improving the performance, allowing better documentation, and has multiple built-in functions.
6. **Migration system for databases**
   Laravel migration system helps to expand the structure of the database of the web application without re-creating every time developers make a change. Owing to this feature, the risk of losing data is very less. It not only offers the facility to change the database structure but it helps to do this by using PHP code instead of SQL. In addition to this, Laravel Schema Builder helps to create database tables and inserts indices or columns promptly.
7. **Unit-Testing**
   Many web app developers like Laravel due to the way it facilitates unit testing. This framework of PHP web development is capable of running many tests to ensure that new changes done by programmers do not unexpectedly break anything in the web application. Generally, laravel is considered to have stable releases in the industry as it is careful of the known failures. In addition to this, it makes it easy to write unit-tests for its own code.
8. **Security**
   Application security is one of the most important concerns in web application development. While developing an application, every programmer has to use some effective ways to make it secure. Laravel takes care of the web application security within its own framework. It uses hashed and salted password that means the password would never save as the plain text in a database. It also uses “Bcrypt Hashing Algorithm” in order generate an encrypted representation of a password. Additionally, this PHP web development framework uses prepared SQL statements that make injection attacks unimaginable.

**Wrapping Up:**
All the above-mentioned features make PHP Laravel framework awesome and highly preferred framework. This framework is continuously becoming popular among developers and businesses for its unique, classic architecture, where developers create their own infrastructure that is specifically designed for their application.

If you are a business owner and want to develop your next web application project on Laravel Framework, feel free to contact: PixelCrayons: a leading PHP web app development
Ref:https://www.pixelcrayons.com/blog/web/8-top-features-stats-facts-about-php-laravel-framework/

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just use your existing HTML templates as your Blade templates in your Laravel app. Blade templates are essentially HTML with some PHP on it so you can get and display data from the backend.